# Mysqli delete query

Tags: php, mysqli

When creating a mysqli delete query how can I run a PHP code to delete the files associated with the info deleted?

I know of `mysqli::$affected_rows` but it doesn't really help me.

Comment: This is why you should store the files in the db, not the paths.

Comment: @vascowhite What do you mean?

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/unlink    @vasco: files in the db are RARELY a good idea. the minor efficiency gain from a delete query killing the "file" as well is NOT enough to make up for all the other trouble it brings

Answer (score 2):

The following line deleted **all** the rows that contained the word "Cron" in the 'Title' column.

```
mysqli_query($con,"delete from `foexstco_rr`.`Timings` where `Title`='Cron'");
```

The next line deleted **everything**.

```
mysqli_query($con,"delete from `foexstco_rr`.`Timings`");
```

This line deleted the rows that contained the 3 conditions. Note that ** and ** had to separate each condition.

```
mysqli_query($con,"delete from `foexstco_rr`.`Timings` where `Number`='77' and `Title`='Cron' and `Cols`='1'");
```

If you printed the MySqli response, "1" will mean that the command has been carried out but it does not necessarily mean that any rows have been deleted. "0" means the command has been incorrectly written.

Answer (score 0):

You can run two queries.That would be like :

```
SELECT id, relevant_field from my_table WHERE the_condition_for_the_rows_to_delete.
```

and then a second query :

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id IN (the_ids_you_got_with_the_first_select)
```

After that you the delete the files associated with the result of the first query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `unlink()` function to delete the files ([docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)).

First do a query to get the file location, then run a loop through results:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,file_path FROM table WHERE whatever")->fetch_assoc();
foreach($results as $result) {
    unlink($row['file_path']);
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = " . $row['id']);
}
```

Make sure you sanitize any user-submitted input to avoid SQL injections.

Edit: This **is not** the most efficient way to do it -- I've demonstrated this way for code simplicity, you would be better off adding the ids to an array and then deleting all of the rows in a single query.